# How to run a program in WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, wcf, web-crawler

I am new to WCF and i am designing a project in which i want to run a crawler program (coded in c#) which crawlers some websites and it stores the crawled data in the tables of database (sql server db). I want that crawler runs repeatedly after 30 minutes and updated the database.

I want to then use the service on my hosted platform so that i can use the data from tables in web form (i.e. .aspx page)

Is it okay to use WCF for this purpose ?

Please suggest me how to move on ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to use WCF for? For the service that reads from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a WCF service to do this but I would go for another setup:

1. I'd build a Windows application that is scheduled to run every 30 minutes by the Windows Task Scheduler. A simple console application might be fine.
2. I'd use a Web application (possibly ASP MVC) to query the database.

As you can see there is no need to use WCF at all.

An exception can/must be made when the server is not yours but you are using a hosting provider who doesn't allow you to schedule a Windows task. In that case you might want to run the crawling process by hand through the web application and have it repeat itself after 30 minutes.

Some hosting providers do allow the scheduling of tasks but in a different way so it might be worth to investigate.

Comment: Thanks but for being stucked with different suggestions i am still not able to make any choice of how to proceed ? So please elobrate and give a more clear prospective of how to do this ? Its like i am designing something like Google News (college level project only) but stuck with cralwling and updating db tables in Shared Hosting environment. Please suggest.

Comment: Do you know how to create an ASP.NET web site + database and add, update and retrieve data from the database? If not, study that first. If you have questions about that ask them on SO but do not expect us to do your work.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is responsible for communication between 2 points with different channel technology. you will use WCF if you want to send/receive some data between two point regardless channel technology (TCP/UDP/NetPipe/MSMQ , ...)

But you first need to design you crawler application which is configured to fetch data from your target web sites, then you need to design a schedular application using 
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/
to run your crawlers.

after running and storing your web pages you can use WCF if you need to do replication or synchronization with center server but it is optional